# DateTime setting format string

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime

I send request to server. Later i get response

```
void feed_OnStreamTrade(string symbol, int tradeFlags, object tradeConditions, byte tradeExchange, double tradePrice, int tradeSize, DateTime tradeDatetime)
  {
    //code
  }
```

I must get time in the format

> yyyy MM dd HH mm ss FFF

but I get it without milliseconds (without FFF)

Screenshot

[image]

I do not understand. Windows cuts milliseconds?

Comment: Hovering over your variable in VS in debug mode doesn't mean anything.  That just shows you the result of `DateTime.ToString()` which will just use some default formatting which typically doesn't include milliseconds. If you want the milliseconds, you have to explicitly request that information by supplying the correct format string.

Answer (score 4):

Surely Windows doesn't cuts milliseconds from datetime. But Visual Studio by default doesn't shows them. Just expand baloon on your screenshot and you will see milliseconds (of course, if they are actually present in your datetime value).

[image]

Comment: Well, in your case milliseconds could be trimmed somewhere else. Are you sure your server really sends you time having milliseconds? Anyway, it is neither Windows nor .NET problem. It is somewhere in your application or server.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the format-coding you want, why dont you apply it?

```
DateTime test = new DateTime(2015, 08, 05, 11, 05, 05, 55);
MessageBox.Show(test.ToString("yyyy MM dd HH mm ss FFF"));
```

*Output:* `2015 08 05 11 05 05 055`

You can also pick out the milliseconds only:

`MessageBox.Show(test.Millisecond.ToString());`

*Output:* `055`

So no, milliseconds are NOT cutted. They are just not visible. You can go for calculations anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are just showing what Visual Studio is showing in the quickwatch. Visual Studio could be just hiding milliseconds.

In your code if you do:

```
quoteDateTime.Millisecond
```

You should get the milliseconds, if it comes as 0 it is probably being removed somewhere in the pipeline between the service response and your method.